# Can I clone the HDD on my aging Dell laptop and install in some way on a Mac mini?

Tags: windows, mac

I am acquiring a late 2012 Mac Mini. Can I make a clone/disk image of my Dell HDD running Windows 7 to install on the Mac. I need Windows as I have software thhat I use occasionally that is Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Although you can run Windows on an Apple machine using Bootcamp, you need OSX installed first. Additionally, your Windows install will likely not have the right drivers to boot on an Apple machine. On top of that, your license for Windows will be a Dell OEM license, therefore tied to your Dell machine. You'll need to buy a new license

Comment: Thanks Jake. I have the Mac now, it has Mavericks installed.